# I have installed SSL and Also Fixed Insecure Content, still i get Your Connection to this site is not fully secure

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3EyD.png)

This is wordpress site Running on ec2 and i recently isntalled aws ACM ssl certificate and fixed mixed content issues, still i get i am getting Your Connection to this site is not fully secure

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clear the local cache. I tried opening your domain and the certificate is valid and everything is with https.